# How can I click on a DOM element and have it pass as a variable using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, web

How do I set up a table so that when the user clicks a row, the data from that row is sent to a PHP script which is loaded into a section on the website?

Basically, I want to partially-populate a data entry form, which I can then add more data to, and then submit the form.

I want to set up the JavaScript so that the click event loads the web form (easy) but this web form will INCLUDE some data from the record that was fetched.

So the order of the data flow would be:

1. Client-browser (user clicks on the row, JavaScript)
2. The data-attribute for that specific row is used to fetch data from the database associated with that attribute (php)
3. Present a web form

### Here is the Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-recordId");
    $('#section2').load('data_entry_form.php?id='+id);
});
```

### Here is the PHP for the Web Form

```
<html>

<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = ("
    SELECT a_aif.aif_id, a_aif.fee_source_id, a_aif.company_name_per_sedar, a_aif.document_filing_date
    FROM a_aif
        LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining
            ON a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
    WHERE a_aif.aif_id = :id
    ORDER BY aif_id DESC");
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

?>

<?php echo $id; ?> <br>
<?php echo $row[fee_source_id]; ?> <br>
<?php echo $row[company_name_per_sedar]; ?> <br>
<?php echo $row[document_filing_date]; ?> <br>

<form>
<input type="date"> </input>
<br>
<input list="auditors" placeholder="Auditor" />
<datalist id="auditors">
    <option value="/Foo" />
</datalist>
<br>
<input list="city" placeholder="City" />
<datalist id="city">
    <option value="Bar" />
</datalist>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" value="Submit" />

</form>

</html>
```

**QUESTIONS**

- what is the point of making a data-attribute equal to the first cell
  of each row? Can't I just use the data in the first cell of each row
  to use as the "id"?
- If 1 is true, then I suppose I should be using the `data` element instead of the `attr` element?
- the PHP is not working! I get this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object.."

Comment: @gamehelp16 could you elaborate?

Comment: you can search about AJAX on google. I'm using phone now

Answer (score 1):

So many problems, do you know the basics of what you're doing here?

You Javascript is sending the record ID using the `id=` parameter, but your PHP is using `$_GET['rowid']`. You need to change one of them to match the other.

You need to assign it to a variable:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

You need to change `rowid` in the SQL to `:rowid`, and prepare the statement:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar... I've updated my code above to reflect the most recent version. I must admit, I'm very confused. I am so close though! Please see updated code (there is an error in the PHP)

Comment: You didn't update the SQL to add the keyword for the parameter, and you're not executing the statement.

Comment: I have not updated the PHP to execute the $sth and also updated the SQL to include the Keyword. Really not clear on this colon before the "rowid" which has been set as "id" now, and agrees to the JavaScript

Comment: You need to read up on PDO prepared statements. When you put a `:keyword` in the SQL, you have to use `$stmt->bindParam()` to associate a variable to it, or provide an array of mappings as an argument to `$stmt->execute()`.